# Unable to uninstall angular/cli

Tags: ubuntu, angular-cli

I tried this: 
    npm uninstall -g @angular/cli and npm uninstall -g angular-cli
Got this:
    up to date in 0.048s
I am not able to delete angular cli I need to install angular 6.2.3 and node also unable to delete it need to install node 10.11.0

Thanks

Comment: So what does `npm list -g --depth=0` show you now? Does `ng` still work on the command line?

Comment: '/usr/local/lib
└── (empty)
' It gives this command

Comment: So why do you think you *haven't* uninstalled the global Angular CLI?

Comment: I still have angular 6.0.0 and cant install angular 6.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli (add sudo in the start if using Linux)
npm cache clean --force / npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

add @ in front of npm package  to install specific package 
e.g `npm install -g @angular/cli@7.1.0`

Comment: think works perfectly, but when I try ng -v  it shows previous angular version

Comment: I guess you are checking ng -v from inside your project, run ng -v outside your project

Comment: I have old version npm(9.11.2) I am also trying to update it by (sudo apt install nodejs npm) ,shows 'The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Conflicts: npm
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'

Comment: @AkshayRajput I have the same problem and I am running ng --version from outside a project... although npm list -g --depth=0 does not show anything the ng --version command shows me that I have the cli version 8 installed....

Comment: It is not working on Mac.  I tried it all (with sudo) and also npm verify cache --force but none work.  Issuing ng -version still shows old 9+ version I had installed before.